# Bash expansion hexadecimal

Tags: bash, brace-expansion, numeric-data, hex

I would like to know if there is a way of using bash expansion to view all possibilities of combination for a number of digits in hexadecimal. I can expand in binaries

In base 2:

```
echo {0..1}{0..1}{0..1}
```

Which gives back:

```
000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
```

In base 10:

```
echo {0..9}{0..9}
```

Which gives back:

```
00  01 02...99
```

But in hexadecimal:

```
echo {0..F}
```

Just repeat:

```
{0..F}
```

Comment: Note that `echo {0-9A-F}` works in zsh with the `BRACE_CCL` option.

Comment: Note that in base 10 you could also say `{00..99}` to get the same output.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can; you just need to break the range `{0..F}` into two separate ranges `{0..9}` and `{A..F}`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {{0..9},{A..F}}{{0..9},{A..F}}
00
01
...
FE
EF
```

Comment: This is a nicer trick than manually write each digit in 0-9A-F!

Answer (score 15):

Using `printf`:

```
$ printf '%.2x\n' {0..255}
```

The format string `%.2x` says to format the output as a zero-filled, two-digit, lower-case, hexadecimal number (`%02x` would have done the same).

If you want upper-case, use `%.2X`.

Bash only understands base 10 integer ranges or ranges between ASCII characters in brace expansions of intervals.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible but it isn't nice:

```
echo {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F}{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F}
```

As far as I can tell `bash` has no notion of hex ranges.